# Xcode not SVN commit not clickable

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I'm having a problem with my Xcode
I set my svn settings in the account settings seems to connect just fine
then I want go to the project I want to commit to the server when I click on source control the only clickable thing is checkout. I tried this like 20 times. It just creates a map with the name of the SVN server that's it.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The commit button is enabled only it that project on which you are working is checked out from SVN repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are just creating the appropriate folder for it but not putting your project in it.

Try this. do the checkout again like you already did before, then locate the project you want to sync with your SVN, place it into the folder that was created when you used the "Checkout" function. Now open your project again from within this folder. You should be able to commit/push/pull etc. your project now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually figured this out already but still it worked for me so I'll accept it as awnser :)